# Vue table field formatting

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, primevue

I am trying to format date from unix timestamp to human friendly date, but I got stuck. I would like it to work in this way:

```html
<Column field="createdAt" header="Created at">{{ new Date(this).toLocaleString() }}</Column>
```

but I do not know how could I refer to that field particular cell. Someone can help? Here is the rest of my code:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <DataTable :value="filters">
      <Column field="id" header="Id"></Column>
      <Column field="highlight" header="Highlight"></Column>
      <Column field="usage" header="Usage"></Column>
      <Column field="createdAt" header="Created at">{{ new Date(this.$data.createdAt).toLocaleString() }}</Column>
    </DataTable>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import DataTable from 'primevue/datatable'
import Column from 'primevue/column'
import { ref, defineComponent } from 'vue'
import { DynamicFilterRowDto } from "@/api/api";
import { getDynamicFilters } from "@/service/data";

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'DynamicFilters',
  components: {
    DataTable,
    Column,
  },
  setup: () => {
    const filters = ref<DynamicFilterRowDto[] | undefined>()

    const fetch = async () => {
      filters.value = await getDynamicFilters()
    }
    fetch()
    return { filters, formatOptions: { format: "MM-dd-yyyy", type: "date" }  }
  },

})
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

The `<Column>` component has a [`body` slot](https://www.primefaces.org/primevue/showcase/#/datatable), whose `data` [slot prop](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-slots.html#abbreviated-syntax-for-lone-default-slots) provides the row data corresponding to the array element in `filters[]`. You could therefore use `data` to access `createdAt`:

```html
<Column field="createdAt" header="Created at">
  <template #body="{ data }">{{ new Date(data.createdAt).toLocaleString() }}</template>
</Column>
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/customizing-column-data-in-primevue-datatable-0uz3h?file=/src/App.vue:201-369)

Answer (score 0):

In Vue 3+ you can still do it like tony19 did:

```
<Column field="createdAt" header="Created at">
  <template #body="slotProps">{{ new Date(slotProps.data.createdAt).toLocaleString() }}</template>
</Column>
```